# Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service failed to load

Tags: fedora

When I run this command to install Couchbase Server

```
sudo rpm --install couchbase-server-community-4.0.0.centos7.x86_64.rpm
```

in my Fedora 22, I got an error below:

> Starting couchbase-server (via systemctl): Failed to start couchbase-server.service: Unit couchbase-server.service failed to load: No such file or directory. [Failed]
>
> You have successfully installed Couchbase Server.

How can I fixed this error?

Comment: If you answered this, please update this question with the solution.  I'd like to know it :)

Comment: @BradWood The answer below works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CentOS 7 I solved this by creating /lib/systemd/system/couchbase-server.service with the following:

```
# -*- mode: conf-unix; -*-
[Unit]
Description = Couchbase Server
Documentation = http://docs.couchbase.com
After = network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier = couchbase
User = couchbase
Type = forking
PIDFile=/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/couchbase-server.pid
WorkingDirectory = /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase
LimitNOFILE = 40960
LimitCORE = unlimited
LimitMEMLOCK = unlimited
ExecStart = /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -noinput -detached > /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs/start.log 2>&1
ExecStop = /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server -k

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Enable with:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable couchbase-server && systemctl restart couchbase-server
```

Comment: Update, this is a known issue now with the latest version of CentOS.  See this forum topic: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/centos-7-couchbse-server-cannot-start-the-service/6261 and this tech note: http://support.couchbase.com/entries/107347963-CentOS-7-2-Breaks-Couchbase-Server-Service-Script

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by removing symlink **/etc/rc.d/init.d/couchbase-server** and copying the init file **/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase_init.d** directly to **/etc/rc.d/init.d**

```
rm /etc/rc.d/init.d/couchbase-server && cp /opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase_init.d /etc/rc.d/init.d/couchbase-server
```

and then systemctl command started to work. systemd maybe doesn't support symlink.